# Java Eclipse accessing xml document

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

Hi everyone im trying to access a xml file but the system can't find the xml file, there is always this error (The system could not locate the specified file)

```
package intro;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class intro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse("hello.xml");
            Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
            Node textNode = root.getFirstChild();
            System.out.println( textNode.getNodeValue() );
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.out.print("Error analyzing the xml doc");
            }}}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2Xo.jpg)

[package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9RPb.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<display>Hello World!</display>
```

i would appreciate the help

Comment: try putting your .xml file in "src/main/resources" folder. In that way it'll read  direct from the source path.

Comment: Or replace `builder.parse("hello.xml");` with the actual file/path, for example `builder.parse("drive:/yourpath/hello.xml");` or `builder.parse(fileObject);`